# Karate framework basic access authentication

Tags: karate

I have this:

```
Background:
     * url 'http://guest:guest@localhost:15672'

Scenario:
    Given path 'some_path'
```

Is there any other way to specify user/pass (guest/guest in this case) outside from URL?

Comment: question not clear at all, voting to close

Comment: I am asking for a better way to handle basic access authentication (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). For example, in cURL you can use -u or --user flag (for example -u user:pass) to indicate user and pasword. Maybe in karate there was something like *auth user:pass or maybe I can add an issue in your tracker.

Comment: there is no better way, just manually form the URL like you are doing, it is absolutely fine. you are the first ever to have asked for this in 3 years, so I'm sure this is like a 0.01% use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No what you are doing is fine unless the end-point actually supports headers such as `Authorization`. Manually form the url, you should be good.

```
* url 'http://guest:guest@localhost:15672'
```